# Bootstrap 4 Grid 14 col same size in 2 rows

Tags: grid, bootstrap-grid

I need to build a bootstrap grid with 14 columns in 2 rows (7 in each row) as you may see in picture below
[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNgD1.png)

https://codepen.io/amaro-chapel/pen/KKzVKgz (BUT WITH 7 COLUMNS on 2 rows!)

But so fare I haven't figure out a way to accomplish that. the columns has to be all time with the same size, and when the user resize the page or open in small device, like smartphone, the grid columns should stay stacked.

If I change the col-md-2 to simply col the columns during the resize will be with different sizes... and I don't want that.

Could someone please help me the get what I need. I know that are some other examples on the stackoverflow but none of them works for I need.

[What I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o71kh.png)

https://codepen.io/amaro-chapel/pen/WNwQqxv

My code:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">



<style type="text/css">
[class*="col-"] {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}




</style>

</head>

<body>

 <br />

 <div class="container-fluid">

   <div class="row ">

  <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center" style="min-width:200px;">
    <div>1</div>        
    <div>SOME TEXT</div>               
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center" style="min-width:200px;">
    <div>2</div>        
    <div>SOME TEXT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center" style="min-width:200px;">
    <div>3</div>        
    <div>SOME TEXT</div>                  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center" style="min-width:200px;">
    <div>4</div>  
    <div>SOME TEXT</div>     
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center" style="min-width:200px;">
    <div>5</div>        
    <div>SOME TEXT</div>       
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center" style="min-width:200px;">
    <div>6</div>          
     <div>SOME TEXT</div>        
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center" style="min-width:200px;">
    <div>7</div>        
    <div>SOME TEXT</div>      
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center" style="min-width:200px;" >
    <div>8</div>        
    <div>SOME TEXT</div>               
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center" style="min-width:200px;">
    <div>9</div>        
    <div>SOME TEXT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center" style="min-width:200px;">
    <div>10</div>        
    <div>SOME TEXT</div>                  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center" style="min-width:200px;">
    <div>11</div>  
    <div>SOME TEXT</div>     
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center" style="min-width:200px;">
    <div>12</div>        
    <div >SOME TEXT</div>       
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center" style="min-width:200px;">
    <div>13</div>          
     <div>SOME TEXT</div>        
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 center-block text-center" style="min-width:200px;">
    <div>14</div>        
    <div>SOME TEXT</div>      
  </div>


 </div>



</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance,
KAPEL

Answer (score 0):

I was just playing around with it and set all the `col-md-2` to `col-md-1`.
I also set the `min-width: 200px;` and `max-width: 250px;`.
You will also want to have two row wrappers, one around `1-7` and one around `8-14`
Try that and hopefully you get something like you're asking for.

Comment: thanks for your reply. If I understand... you change col-md-2 to col-md-1 and on the style you also add  style="min-width:200px;max-width: 250px", right? If so, it didn´t work.

Comment: I edited my response after to include adding another div.row wrapper. one wrapper around 1-7 and one wrapper around 8-14. Hope this works!

Comment: As you can see in pic below... When I resize the browser... stays unformated... Because of that I didn't wrap a div.row around 1-7 and another row.div wrapper around 8-14... to avoid this problem.. I think it has to be simple solution with bootstrap.. but i don't know...
https://i.ibb.co/myqnB00/pic2.png

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap grid divides the page into 12 columns by default, however you are able to create as many columns as you want by using the "col" class without specifying the size. This way the row will be divided into as many columns as you create.

Example: https://codepen.io/MimoTooThanks/pen/RwaWzjO

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">1</div>
        <div class="col">2</div>
        <div class="col">3</div>
        <div class="col">4</div>
        <div class="col">5</div>
        <div class="col">6</div>
        <div class="col">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">8</div>
        <div class="col">9</div>
        <div class="col">10</div>
        <div class="col">11</div>
        <div class="col">12</div>
        <div class="col">13</div>
        <div class="col">14</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

remember you still can use responsive classes in conjunction with that, like so: https://codepen.io/MimoTooThanks/pen/zYqvVMj

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md">1</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

"col-12" says these columns will span 12 columns (full page) at any screen size since it's not specified.

Screens bigger than medium will display the columns side by side however. That's because of the "col-md" class. In this case, because there is no column size defined, this is basically saying "if the screen is medium or bigger, make the columns equal" which also overrides the previous "col-12" class.

Please take a look at the bootstap grid docs:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

**EDIT:**

See the example here on forcing your columns to stay equal width by using max-width and a media query that matches a bootstrap breakpoint: https://codepen.io/MimoTooThanks/pen/gOraVvm

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .col {
        max-width: 14.28571428571429%
    }
}
```

Note: you'll need to re-calculate the percentage if you change the number of columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answser. As I said in question I already tried with using just "col" and using explicity 2 rows.. but if you try put some text inside of col div rather than of just 1 or 2... you will see that columns will be unformed (with different sizes), do you understant what I mean?

Comment: @akpel Sorry, missed that part. In this case I'd suggest setting a max-width for the columns under a custom breakpoint that matches one of bootstrap. See the breakpoints here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

Comment: @akpel I've updated my post to hopefully anwser your question better.

Comment: basically I need this https://codepen.io/amaro-chapel/pen/OJNyKvg but using bootstrap 4.

Comment: you getting close to I need but remains 2 pbs: First one, each column must have minimum width, and Second on resize on browser should be stacked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can give five col-2 and two col-1, that's how you can have 7 columns in one row.Hope this works.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-2">c1</div>
<div class="col-2">c2</div>
<div class="col-2">c3</div>
<div class="col-2">c4</div>
<div class="col-2">c5</div>
<div class="col-1">c6</div>
<div class="col-1">c7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx for your code. but I need that all columns be of same size...

Comment: then how about you give class="col-1" to all the siven divs for one row and then use another row for 7 columns with same class..that's how you can give 7 columns to 2 rows.